# ScheduledExecutorService, schedule different tasks at different intervals

Tags: java, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to have two tasks - HandlerA and HandlerB being executed every 10 and every 20 seconds respectively.
If this solution is wrong, what is the best way to achieve this?

```
ScheduledExecutorService stp = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(8);
stp.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HandlerA(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
stp.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HandlerB(), 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

is the scheduled task overwritten, when I schedule another one?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: only the first task was executed. I admit that my sample code was not suitable for the testing purposes. The first task just failed silently and therefore was not re-scheduled, as I found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You are scheduling 2 separate tasks. Your ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor has core pool size = 8, this is more than enough to execute 2 scheduled tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you ask? That solution is fine. Each invocation of `scheduleAtFixedRate` starts an individual scheduler i.e. adding `HandlerA` twice runs it with two independent schedulers.